# sum of exponentials to non-integer power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I have the expression
\begin{equation}
(e^{at}+e^{bt}+e^{ct})^{v}
\end{equation}
for some a,b,c which isn't important. I'd like to take a limit $t\rightarrow \infty,v\rightarrow 0,vt=\text{constant}$. My question is, is there anyway to manipulate the bracket, e.g. if it $v$ was an integer the binomial theorem, so that I can have $tv$ as the exponent to something?

Comment: Can't you use a sequence $v_n$ and $t_n$ such as $v_nt_n=c$, with $t_n$ going to $\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a, b, c$ are *real* numbers then you can assume that $a \ge b \ge c$
and write your expression as
$$
(e^{at}+e^{bt}+e^{ct})^{v} = e^{avt}(1+e^{(b-a)t}+e^{(c-a)t})^{v}
$$
The first factor $e^{avt}$ is constant, and the second factor has the limit $1$
for $v \to 0$ because
$$
 1 \le 1+e^{(b-a)t}+e^{(c-a)t} \le 3
$$
for $t > 0$, and  $\lim_{v \to 0} 3^v = 1$.

Comment: How does the last inequality imply that the limit is $1$? You cannot apply the squeeze theorem on it because $1 \neq 3$.

Comment: @rubik: $\lim_{v \to 0} 1^v = 1$ and $\lim_{v \to 0} 3^v = 1$.

Comment: Ahh I had misread a bit. Thank you for clarifying it to me.